# How can I pass variable in my fetch request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

I'm using react native and try to understand some examples.

I've got a problem

I'm trying to pass latitude in my fetch but I've got a problem who say me "latitude" don't exist

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  region: {
    latitude: LATITUDE,
      longitude: LONGITUDE,
      latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
      longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
  },
  markers: [],
  loaded: false
}

}

componentDidMount() {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  (position) => {
    console.log(position);
    this.setState({
      region: {
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
      }
    });
  },
  (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
  { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 200000, maximumAge: 1000 },
  );
  this.getLocations()
}


getLocations(){
  return fetch('https://***&geofilter.distance='+latitude+'%2C2.3883402698750875%2C2000') //here
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseData =>{
    var markers = [];
```

Can you help me, thanks :)

Comment: *"I've got a problem who say me don't exist"* Please copy and paste the **actual** error message into the question, and tell us what line the error refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `getLocations`, you're trying to use a `latitude` variable, but there is none in scope there. You may have wanted `this.state.region.latitude`.

If you're trying to use `this.state.region.latitude`, though, you need to move your call to `getLocations` in `componentDidMount` so that it's *inside* a state change completion handler:

```
componentDidMount() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (position) => {
      console.log(position);
      this.setState({
        region: {
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
          longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
        }
      },
      () => {                   // ***
        this.getLocations();    // ***
      });                       // ***
    },
    (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
    { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 200000, maximumAge: 1000 },
  );
  // *** Not here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are storing your latitude in state so you need to call it as `this.state.region.latitude`

```
return fetch('https://***&geofilter.distance='+this.state.region.latitude+'%2C2.3883402698750875%2C2000')
```

Comment: Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `region.latitude` is marked as required in `MapView`, but its value is `undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

Try using your fetch like this:

```
return fetch('https://***&geofilter.distance='+this.state.region.latitude+'%2C2.3883402698750875%2C2000')
```